# Why is the information from the node shown incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a graph with my javascript code that I created myself. By clicking on a node, the list of publications assigned to a keyword is to be called up. The currently selected node is to be highlighted in the. When I click on a node with my current code, I get the complete name of the selected keyword in the grey box. Only when I click on one of the keywords do I get the first names, surnames etc. How can I make it so that when I click on a node I get the first name, surname directly? If I click on another node, the information from the other node is shown and the previously shown information from the node should then disappear.Im using D3.js Verison 6.

```
  <script src="persona.js"></script>
  <div id="detail_box"></div> // The Detail_box is a grey box in which the information is shown.
```

```
        node.onclick = function() {
          keyName = node.innerText;
          document.getElementById("detail_box").innerText = keyName + "\nFirstname: " + persona[keyName].firstname;
        }
        document.getElementById("detail_box").appendChild(node);});
      })
      .call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged).on("end", dragended));
```

Comment: Print `console.log(graph.nodes)` before `var node = svg.append("g")`. What is the structure of nodes array?

Comment: If i print out my "graph.nodes" its saying "undefined". I have adjusted the method where I output my nodes and links above.

Comment: ... and you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes. im getting the same error message. Iv also print out my link `console.log(graph.links)` and im also getting "undefined".

Comment: Post you code that builds `graph` data

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky i have posted it. I also noticed that this method does not work for me. I wanted to read out the node texts: `node.append("title").text(d => d.id);`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky How can I make it so that when I click on a node, I get the information I need? Because currently when I click on a node I get the complete name of the keyword. Only when I click on this keyword do I get the information about the keyword.

Comment: It's hard to see because I don't have a snippet or fiddle to work with... Can you post one?

Comment: ive solved it. thx